# How to suspend the typescript `unused` error consoles

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

In my angular cli, I am getting the following error:

`jest.config.js is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.`

as well there is no of other files i kept at present without use. ( will be used later )

now I would like to suspend this errors from the console. how to config it?

any one help me?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    },
    "types": ["jest"],
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "esModuleInterop":true,
    "allowJs":true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
     "@core/*": ["src/app/core/*"],
     "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"]
    },
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "paths": {
      "globalize": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize"
      ],
      "globalize/*": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/*"
      ],
      "cldr": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr"
      ],
      "cldr/*": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/*"
      ],
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
   "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
}
```

As a suggestion i updated my exclude array like this:

```
"exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.js",
        "src/jestGlobalMocks.ts", //still getting error
        "src/setup-jest.ts" //still getting error
    ],
```

Comment: Did you try adding this file to 'exclude' ?

Comment: there is no.of files to add, looking for any disable, enable solution if any

Comment: try remove `"allowJs":true,` bcs as per [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) `JS files (.js and .jsx) are also included if allowJs is set to true`

Comment: @jitender - can i update to `"allowJs":false` - it it ok?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you have to give it a try check if that works i think it should work

Comment: @jitender - it's not works, since all are under ts file ext

Comment: what if you add `"**/*.js"` to exclude array

Comment: @jitender - can you see my update in question?

Comment: @3gwebtrain 
`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "extensions" : {
             "**/*.ts": "TS",
             "**/*.es": "JS",
             "src/**/*.js": "TS" // treat all JS files inside src as TS
        }
    }
}`  check this configuration for allow js extension.

Comment: @SavajPatel getting error as `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'extensions'`

Comment: have you try with sourceMap false in tsconfig.json file its helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove this line from "include" "src/**/*.ts" from tsconfig.app.json

Comment: If you remove you got a "An unhandled exception occurred: error TS18003"